# Two headers in a table, show in one a table responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a responsive table that meets the following objective:

[image: that looks like this.]

I tried to do it with tables and divs, but it doesn't work...

```css
#states {
    font-family: "gothic";
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    z-index: 99px;
}
```

```html
<table id="states" style="overflow-x:auto; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 4px; padding-right: 10px; border-left: none; border-right: #444242;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: left;  border-radius:  15px 9000px 20px .1px;    font-size: 10px; font-family: 'gothic'; background-color: #00508e; border:none;
   width: 5cm; padding: 10px; color: white;">
   A
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr style="margin: -0cm -1cm 0cm 1cm;border: 0; border-top: 3px solid #5b5b5e; line-height: 1; z-index: 1; ">
  <th  style="font-size:12px; border:left: #444242; border-right: none;">
   a1
  </th>
  <th style="border:none; font-size:12px;">
   b1
  </th>
  <th style="border:none; font-size:12px;">
   c1
  </th>
  <th style="border:none; font-size:12px;">
   d1
  </th>
  <th style="background-color:#d6e7ee; border:none; font-size:12px;">
   e1
  </th>
  <th style="background-color:#d6e7ee; border:none; font-size:12px;">
   f1
  </th>
  <th style="background-color:#d6e7ee; border:none; font-size:12px;">
   g1
  </th>
  <th style="background-color:#d6e7ee; border:none; font-size:12px;">
   h1
  </th>
  <th style="background-color:#d6e7ee; border-left: none; font-size:12px;">
   i1
  </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr style="background-color: #fff; font-size:12px;">
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   a2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   b2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   c2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   d2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   e2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   f2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   g2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   h2
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px;">
   i2
  </td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I add the class table-responsive and I tried do it with divs, but it doesn't also work because it has **two headers**: **A y a1, b1, c1...**

What should I do?

With DIVS this is my result:

[image: With DIVS this is my result.]

Comment: Put your code in a text editor and align it properly - then copy/paste back here so we can read it without scrolling back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may  look at mediaqueries and flex  to break the layout.

Use the `colspan` attribute efficiently(in other words build correctly your `table`).

every style should be moved to the style sheet.

example *(run it also in full page to see mediaqueries at work)*

**note**: two `thead` are required so it can break and one stand aside `tbody`.

```css
#states {
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#states td,
#states thead + thead th {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  background: #56D0A0
}

#states td {
  background: #5BD0D0
}

#states th[colspan="2"] {
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 0 10em 0 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'gothic';
  background-color: #00508e;
  border: none;
  width: 5cm;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

thead:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5b5b5e;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {/* break point*/
  table#states {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 15em;
  }
  #states thead:first-of-type {
    width:100%;
  }
  #states thead:first-of-type [colspan="2"] {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  thead:first-of-type th {
    display: none;
  }
  thead:first-of-type th[colspan="2"] {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #states thead,
  #states tbody,
  #states tr,
  #states thead + thead th,
  #states td {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  /* you'll need more flex to put th and td side by side if content is uneven ,
  but can be seen later */
}
```

```html
<table id="states">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        A
      </th>
      <th colspan="7"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        a1
      </th>
      <th>
        b1
      </th>
      <th>
        c1
      </th>
      <th>
        d1
      </th>
      <th>
        e1
      </th>
      <th>
        f1
      </th>
      <th>
        g1
      </th>
      <th>
        h1
      </th>
      <th>
        i1
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        a2
      </td>
      <td>
        b2
      </td>
      <td>
        c2
      </td>
      <td>
        d2
      </td>
      <td>
        e2
      </td>
      <td>
        f2
      </td>
      <td>
        g2
      </td>
      <td>
        h2
      </td>
      <td>
        i2
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OMG! You are awesome!

Comment: Thanks! I will improve :)